# Yandex API Map - как проверить пересечение границ стран Polyline и расстояние в каждой стране

Tags: javascript, php, yandex-maps-api

Есть две точки A и B, между ними строю Polyline и получаю расстояние с помощью ymaps.coordSystem.geo.getDistance(startPoint, endPoint);
Далее получаю страну точки A и страну точки B через геокодирование.
Если страны разные, то нужно получить длину polyline в каждой стране.
Есть идеи, как это можно сделать? Может как то можно точку на пересечении границ ставить?

Comment: неужели нельзя никак сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому надо, то решил вот так: 
Загрузил регионы на всю карту

```
var regionsResult = ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.regions.load('001'));
```

Далее, я получаю путь от точки А до точки B

```
path = ymaps.coordSystem.geo
      .solveInverseProblem(start, finish).pathFunction;
```

И затем, делю отрезок на 200 точек и проверяю, сменился ли регион, если да, то записываю расстояние до смены региона, ну и отдельно после региона.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 200 ; i++) 
              {
                     // Находим промежуточную точку.
                  var position = path(i/200).point;
                  var region = getRegionByCoords(position);

                  if(country1 != region.name){



                    country1 = region.name;
                    space1 = ymaps.coordSystem.geo.getDistance(coordspl1, position);
                    space2 = ymaps.coordSystem.geo.getDistance(position, coordspl2);

                    string_countries += region.name+'/'; //Записываем список стран через /
                    string_space += ymaps.coordSystem.geo.getDistance(temp_metr, position) +'/'; //Записываем расстояние по странам
                    temp_metr = position;
                    console.log('Всего:' + spaceAll);
                   // console.log('от точки до границы:' + space1);
                   // console.log('от границы до точки:' + space2);



                     $('#space_km').val(spaceAll);

                      myCollectionMetka.add(new ymaps.Placemark(position, {
                            // Покажем в контенте метки пройденное расстояние.
                            iconContent: 'Пересечение границы на '+ymaps.formatter.distance(
                            ymaps.coordSystem.geo.getDistance(start, position)
                            ) 
                            }, {

                     preset: 'islands#blackStretchyIcon',

                            }
                            ));


                  }







            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Прямо так, чтобы в лоб решения не вижу.
Но алгоритм можно построить на базе примера из песочницы Яндекса: [Пересечение маршрута с многоугольником на примере МКАД](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_inside_polygon)

Что изменить:

1. Загрузить в скрипт полигон страны из которой строится маршрут и получить его координаты вместо московского полигона в примере. У Яндекса есть возможность загружать [Регионы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/). Правда получение их координат для своих целей недокументировано, но выцарапать при желании можно попробовать. Либо найти GeoJSON файлы на сторонних ресурсах. Можно и нарисовать этот полигон как в примере.
2. Если полилиния подробная, можно сложить линии до пересечения, и после для получения их длины. Если нет, придётся делить линию, которая пересекает полигон, на меньшие участки и выполнять задачу повторно, чтобы сократить длину пересекающегося участка до приемлемого.
3. В примере используется маршрут, а не полилиния. Можно либо построить нужный маршрут с промежуточными точками (особенно если ваша полилиния именно маршрутная), либо заменить его на полилинию, и разбить на участки уже его.